# How to identify Highcharts datagroup event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'd like to trigger a message when Highcharts groups the data. I want to show the message that this is group data, not real data.

I found some information to disable grouping by:

```
dataGrouping: {enabled:false}
```

but I'd like to find an event that fires when data is auto-grouped which can trigger the message.

How can I achieve that?

```js
$.getJSON('https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts/057b672172ccc6c08fe7dbb27fc17ebca3f5b770/samples/data/large-dataset.json', function(data) {

  // Create a timer
  var start = +new Date();

  // Create the chart
  Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
      events: {
        load: function() {
          if (!window.TestController) {
            this.setTitle(null, {
              text: 'Built chart in ' + (new Date() - start) + 'ms'
            });
          }
        }
      },
      zoomType: 'x'
    },

    rangeSelector: {

      buttons: [{
        type: 'day',
        count: 3,
        text: '3d'
      }, {
        type: 'week',
        count: 1,
        text: '1w'
      }, {
        type: 'month',
        count: 1,
        text: '1m'
      }, {
        type: 'month',
        count: 6,
        text: '6m'
      }, {
        type: 'year',
        count: 1,
        text: '1y'
      }, {
        type: 'all',
        text: 'All'
      }],
      selected: 3
    },

    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
      }
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Hourly temperatures in Vik i Sogn, Norway, 2009-2017'
    },

    subtitle: {
      text: 'Built chart in ...' // dummy text to reserve space for dynamic subtitle
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Temperature',
      data: data.data,
      pointStart: data.pointStart,
      pointInterval: data.pointInterval,
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 1,
        valueSuffix: '°C'
      }
    }]

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o3hcvy8r/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by checking the state of `hasGroupedData` flag when `generatePoints` function. Both `hasGroupedData` and `genearatePoints` belong to a `Series` object. `Highcharts.wrap` function makes the code simple:

```
 (function(H) {
   H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'generatePoints', function(proceed) {
     proceed.call(this);
     console.log('Data grouping applied: ' + (this.hasGroupedData === true));
   });
 })(Highcharts);
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/djvrew2h/

Comment out `forced: true` to check how function works when grouping is not applied.

**Doc about wrapping:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts